# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position,

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error while applying JSON.parse() in a JSON encoded string containing  "" i.e, START OF TEXT Character (<0X02>) in js.
How can I fix this?
I am applying filter_var($string, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW); in my PHP controller for the input which contains the text "xyzzzz | Offshore xyzzz".

For reference,
var xx = "userName":"abcde","title":"xxx Offshore xxx";
xx = JSON.parse(xx);
Console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position

can anyone help to resolve this? It would be appreciated if I could find a solution using PHP filter_var.

Comment: Even here START OF TEXT character is stripped from the string which is posted in my question.

Comment: `var xx = "userName":"abcde","title":"xxx Offshore xxx";` is not valid JS code. You probably want to use an object literal: `var xx = { userName: "abcde", title: "xxx Offshore xxx" };` (you don't need to parse this, `xx` is now an object)

Comment: To make xx a JSON string, you need `var xx = '{"userName":"abcde","title":"xxx Offshore xxx"}';`. You can now parse this, but that seems kinda pointless.